# HighChart - Can draw line between Title and SubTitle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, highcharts

In HighChart, how can I make a green line appear between my title and my subtitle?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uXg9t/190/)

```
title: {
    useHTML: true,
    text: 'Header Text in Line1 </br> Line&nbsp;2 Text',
    style: {
        "text-align": "center"
    }
},    

subtitle: {
    // useHTML: true,
    text: 'SubTitle',
    style: {
        "color": "red",
    }
}
```

[image: Image of what I want]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make the title `display:block` and then set the `left` to `0px`. Then set the width to `100%`. Now the title spans the whole width of the chart. Now apply a bottom border of green color. You will get the desired effect.

In the style property of the title, you could give

```
        "width": '100%',
        "display": 'block',
        "left": 0
```

Have a look at this fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/rwmntze8/

Hope this helps!

PS: Someone *removed* the original image containing the requirements, attached by the OP in the question, during the edits *(You can find it in the edit revisions)*. I have attached it here for reference, in case someone thinks why the green line spans till the end.
[image: Original Requirement posted by the OP]

Answer (score 4):

What you'd need to do is modify the `style` attribute like this:

```
title: {
        useHTML: true,
        text: 'Header Text in Line1 </br> Line&nbsp;2 Text',
        style: {
            "text-align": "center",
            "border-bottom": "1px solid green"
        }
    },
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zywdh.png)

Answer (score 3):

Just need to add an empty css below, nothing more:

```
.highcharts-title {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

Doing it by pure CSS (not by setting element style using JS) gives you the best performance.

**Live example:** http://jsfiddle.net/fqes890o/